# Console shows 'Incorrect integer value' when I try to post form with laravel. Route parameter is not recognized

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, routes

I'm trying to post answers to database that user has submited. Questions are same for different subjects so I have a foreign key to subject_id and user_id. But I always get 500 error.

These are my routes:

```
Route::get('/predmeti/{subject}/analiza', 'AnalizaController@show');
Route::post('predmeti/{subject}/analiza_answers', 'AnalizaAnswerController@store');
```

AnalizaController that gets the show view:

```
public function show(Request $request, $subject_id)
    {
        $analizaquestions=AnalizaQuestion::all();
        return view('analiza.show', compact('analizaquestions'));
    }
```

AnalizaAnswerController used for post method:

```
public function store(Request $request, $subject_id)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'answer'=>'required',
            'analiza_question_id'=>'required',
        ]);
        $validated['user_id']=Auth::id();
        $validated['subject_id']=$subject_id;
        AnalizaAnswer::create($validated);
        return redirect('/predmeti/'.$subject_id);
    }
```

And finally js file used to post it:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function submitAnswers() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#loader').show();
        $('.answer_form').each(function () {
            var answer={};
            answer['analiza_question_id'] = $(this).find('input[name="analiza_question_id"]').val();
            answer['answer'] = $(this).find('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
            console.log(answer);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/predmeti/{subject}/analiza_answers",
                data: answer,
                success: function(data) {
                    window.location.href = "/predmeti/{subject}/analiza";
                },
            });
        });
    }
    $('#btn_submit_answers').click(submitAnswers);
});
```

Every time I try to post I get 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{subject}' for column 'subject_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `analiza_answers` (`answer`, `analiza_question_id`, `user_id`, `subject_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Ne, 1, 56, {subject}, 2019-09-06 16:41:40, 2019-09-06 16:41:40))' and '%7Bsubject%7D' in my route. I don't know how to get the id from my route so I could post to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally posting `{subject}` as `$subject_id` via `/predmeti/{subject}/analiza_answers` in your `ajax` request, but you need to replace `{subject}` with the `$subject_id`.

First, make sure you pass `$subject_id` to your view:

```
public function show(Request $request, $subject_id)
{
    $analizaquestions=AnalizaQuestion::all();
    return view('analiza.show', compact('analizaquestions', 'subject_id'));
}
```

Then, in your `ajax` request, pass the value. If your `javascript` is within a `<script>` element in your `show.blade.php` file, you can simply do:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  function submitAnswers() {
    ...
    $('.answer_form').each(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/predmeti/{{ $subject_id }}/analiza_answers",
        ...
        window.location.href = "/predmeti/{{ $subject_id }}/analiza";
```

Note: `{{ $subject_id }}` is `.blade.php` syntax that outputs the value of your `php` variable `$subject_id`. **This is valid as long as this is a `.blade.php` file and not an external `.js` file.**

If your `js` is in an external `.js` file, you need to assign the value to a `javascript` one before you include your `js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var subjectId = "{{ $subject_id }}";
</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

And make sure you replace the value as required:

```
url: "/predmeti/" + subjectId + "/analiza_answers",
window.location.href = "/predmeti/" + subjectId + "/analiza";
```

At this point, when your `ajax` submits, `$subject_id` in your `public function store()` will be the same value as `public function show()` as you have successfully replaced `{subject}` in the url with the subject ID.